# Passing the Context always fails - Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?

Tags: android, android-context, android-dialog

I am working on an App that has a DialogBuilder Class where I implemented all the Dialogs for the App in order to be able to call them in other Services or Activities; that works very well except in one Activity, where I tried everything to pass the context - it is not working; hence, I would be more than delighted for any hints or help on this, thanks!

The Dialog:

```
public static void bookingConfirmationDialog(Context mContext) {
        if(mContext != null) {
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(GoldbekStorageApp.getInstance(), 0);
            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            dialog.setCancelable(true);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.new_booking_layout);
            dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
            TextView textView = dialog.findViewById(R.id.messageId);
            textView.setText(GoldbekStorageApp.getInstance().messageId);
            Button okButton = dialog.findViewById(R.id.ok);
            okButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            dialog.show();
        }
    }
```

The call of the Dialog:

```
proceedButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Perform action on click
                message.setType(type);
                message.setFromId(fromID);
                message.setToId(toID);
                message.setTypeId(typeID);
                message.setTime(time);
                message.setTitle(title);
                message.setReceiptNo(receiptNo);
                message.setNote(note);
                RestClient.putBookingOnPallet(basic,message,context);
                DialogBuilder.bookingConfirmationDialog(context);
       /*         Intent activityChangeIntent = new Intent( NewProductActivity.this,
                        NewProductActivity.class);
                NewProductActivity.this.startActivity(activityChangeIntent);*/

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be missing something but you could `override onAttach` in the DialogFragment class instead of passing the context in through the constructor.

```
    @Override
    public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
    }
```